# PDO FetchAll() Number Rounding Issue

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, fetchall

I am using PDO to execute Stored Procedures on an MSSQL database. Everything works absolutely brilliantly apart from one small hitch with `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`. When returning floats from the Stored Procedure, instead of returning them with the correct value and decimal place, it is returning the value with extra decimal places like so:

```
Database | Returned by PDO
-----------------------------------
614.9    | 614.89999999999998
1.18     | 1.1799999999999999
```

It seems as if there are rounding issues... I don't understand why it is trying to round the number anyway, surely it should just take the value from the database as it appears?

I have tried:

1. Running the Stored Procedure on the DB and this works absolutely fine, therefore it is definitely something to do with PDO.
2. Running a normal query (instead of a Stored Procedure), and this still produces the same result.

***Obviously I can format the number myself, but this is irrelevant as I have to be sure that what I get from the database is exactly what is in the database!***

Comment: Are you sure it's not the other way around? What you see in the "Database" gets rounded?

Comment: What is the datatype for that column?

Comment: @OneTrickPony Thats a fair point!! How could I know?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Float length 53

Comment: Try inserting `4.21` and `4.1999999` and check what PDO / "Database"  returns in both cases

Comment: "When returning **integers**"...

Comment: @OneTrickPony already on it :-)

Comment: @OneTrickPony I inserted 2.1 and the result is 2.1000000000000001. Very confused!! :-(

Comment: @OneTrickPony I think the problem may lie with how Microsoft handle Floating points in a database...

Comment: Did you try zaq's suggestion? `bindColumn` with `PDO::PARAM_STR`, then fetch with `PDO::FETCH_BOUND` ?

Comment: @OneTrickPony trying that now

Comment: @OneTrickPony Afraid not, still comes out with a load of decimal places

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is how float numbers are stored internally in PHP? Try to read about it [in official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php).

**UPD:**
You may also specify result column as string (PDO::PARAM_STR) with [PDOStatement::bindColumn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php), but I didn't check it.

Comment: Thats interesting, could be this, I will look into it. Thank you

Comment: I have tried both sugestions, sadly neither have solved this. I believe it is to do with how Microsoft handle Floating Points

Comment: can you fix your routine to cast returned values to string (if it an option for you)?

Comment: That was something I looked into and it works but as this SP returns over 500 fields, it is not very practical... I am going to format my numbers using PHP instead...

Comment: can you make a benchmarks of both solutions and publish it here? i would appreciate it very much.

Comment: Any one find a clear answer to this problem other than turning the numbers into a string ?